# How to influence keyboard focus traversal policy in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, focus

Let's say there are two WPF lists. 
I'd like to be able to iterate seamlessly through items it both lists using just keyboard arrow keys.
By default focus scope is limited to iteration within a single container.
Is there any way to help it cross container borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. 
[KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property does the trick. (possible values listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode(v=vs.110).aspx))

The sample can be simplified to:

```
<StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained">
  <ListBox KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
  </ListBox>
  <ListBox KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item A" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item B" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item C" />
  </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

So say there are two ListViews:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="list1" KeyDown="list1_KeyDown">
        <ListViewItem Content="item 1"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="item 2"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="item 3"/>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="list2" Grid.Row="1" KeyDown="list2_KeyDown">
        <ListViewItem Content="item 1"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="item 2"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="item 3"/>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Add two handlers for the KeyDown events:

```
private void list1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.Key) {
        // check for down key
        case Key.Down:
            // if the bottom item is selected
            if (list1.SelectedIndex == list1.Items.Count - 1) {
                // select the next item
                list2.SelectedIndex = 0;
                (list2.Items[0] as UIElement).Focus();
                // make sure nothing else happens
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void list2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.Key) {
        // check for up key
        case Key.Up:
            // if the top item is selected
            if (list2.SelectedIndex == 0) {
                // select the previous item
                int i = list1.Items.Count - 1;
                list1.SelectedIndex = i;
                (list1.Items[i] as UIElement).Focus();
                // make sure nothing else happens
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This will allow seamless vertical transition between the two ListViews using up/down keys. You can add more case blocks to add additional left/right transition or whatever.
I'm sure you can work out how to adapt this to your specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This approach will definitely work, but it looks too winform-ish.
I was hoping to find something a bit more elegant) I believe there should be a better way in wpf.